# error during producing random integer in python

Tags: python

I am using python for producing random in integer between the two value from the user, My code is as follows. I am getting error:

```py
from random import *

i1 = input('Enter the N1 :')
i2 = input('Enter the N2 :')

r = randint({0},{1}.format(i1,i2))

print r
```

Here I am taking i1 and i2 from user and want to produce random integer between i1 and i2.

I am getting the error:

```
File "index.py", line 6
    r = randint({0},{1}.format(i1,i2))
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotation marks/apostrophes to make `{0},{1}` a string:

```
r = randint('{0},{1}'.format(i1,i2))
```

This will pass a string to the random integer function though. The function expects two integers. So all you need to do is:

```
r = randint(i1, i2)
```

Comment: thanks , but I am getting another error after editing this. Error is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 6, in <module>
    r = randint('{0},{1}'.format(i1,i2))
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @chakladar You probably don't want the `format` function here. Just do `r = randint(i1, i2)`

Comment: @AlexThornton Please don't advertise your answer on mine

Answer (score 4):

To fix everything just do:

```
r = random.randint(i1, i2)
```

After fixing the `SyntaxError` you will get another error due to passing a string to `randint`. Just do what I did above to fix that, you don't need `.format` at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, so you don't need to parse strings to integers - `i1` and `i2` are already integers. Instead do:

```
from random import randint

i1 = input('Enter N1:')
i2 = input('Enter N2:')
r = randint(i1, i2)
print r
```

BTW, you are missing quotes for the format string {0},{1}

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're trying to do:

1. Import the `randint` function
2. Get the lower and upper bounds from the user
3. Print out a random integer between (inclusive) the bounds

Here's the code to do that:

```
from random import randint

a = input('Enter the lower bound: ')
b = input('Enter the upper bound: ')

print(randint(a, b))
```

NOTE: If you're using Python 3 you will need to convert a and b to integers e.g.

```
a = int(input('Enter the lower bound: '))
```